# SCSI port vs storport

Tags: windows, winapi, wdk

WHen I call IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT,... )
to set up IRP from my driver, how do I know which driver (storport or scsiport) it is going to considering I have both of them in my drivers folder.  I ahve the source only and no debug environment. Is ther a simple way to figure it out?

Comment: Download WINDDK. In WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\storage\class\disk\disk.c DiskIoctlSmartReceiveDriveData(). This is not allowing me copy paste the code.

Comment: without codes, we can't help.

Comment: If you're going to use StackOverflow, you need to learn how to post.  It most certainly will allow you to paste code into your question, so you need to learn how.  Also, if you insert four spaces before each line of code, it will be highlighted as code and won't be word-wrapped.